# Data table refresh table

Tags: datatables

I have a data table with "edit" link to open custom form in edit mode like,

[image]

When edit link is clicked form is opened in the edit mode something like,

[image]

What I am trying to do is to refresh data table specific record when record is edited and saved in the opened tab without reloading parent window.

Can it be accomplished ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`row().data`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.data%28%29) API method to set data for the row if you store row index or node after user clicked on the row.

```
table.row($row).data(d).draw();
```

If your table data source is Ajax and you update the server after the row has been edited as well via Ajax, it makes sense to reload the table instead with [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29) API method. For example:

```
// Reload table without resetting the current page
table.ajax.reload(null, false);
```